# Session scoped bean behaves as Request scope bean

Tags: java, spring, session-scope

I have Session scope bean which behaves as request scope bean.

I'm using it in Singleton bean, and maybe that's why with second request is has null values?
Code which I used to setup the bean:
In singleton:

```
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

MyBean class:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean, Serializable {
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES, value = {  "my.package.with.bean" })
public class ComponentsConfig {
}
```

MyBean is simple pojo. with getters and setters.
With first request I set values on that bean, with second request in the same class (singleton) I want to read those values, but all values are null. There is no way that something has overrdiden those values.

**EDIT**
How I make requests - It's just simple browser request, and code which read/writes to my session bean lays in filters.

This is singleton:

```
@Service
public class SingletonBean {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;
// here I save the data to session scoped bean
    private void saveUser(LdapContext ctx, String principal) throws NamingException {
        Attributes attributes = getAttributes();
        myBean.setId("id");
        myBean.setName("name");
        myBean.setEmail("email");
        myBean.setTelNum("123");
        myBean.setGroups(Lists.newArrayList("one", "two"));
        myBean.setAddress("address");
    }
// here I try to read data from session scoped bean:
    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo queryForAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals,
            LdapContextFactory ldapContextFactory) throws NamingException {
       // here userInfo will be null
        List<String> userInfo =  myBean.getGroups();
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo authorizationInfo = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        for (String role : userInfo ) {
            authorizationInfo.addRole(role);
        }
        return authorizationInfo;
}
```

}

When user logs in, and he is authenticated, I save his details in session bean. When he tries to open any page method queryForAuthorizationInfo is executed (after chain of filters) and values are null in that object.

Comment: Please show us the relevant read/write code and how you make requests.

Comment: Can you post your Singleton implementation, complete MyBeanImpl class and class that process requests?

Comment: I will also add that session id is the same in moment of saving into bean and when reading from session bean.
@IlyaOvesnov source code added

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis source code added